# CSS3 Box-shadow on pseudo before and after elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, box-shadow

I need to create something like this to separate sections in a mobile design:

[image]

I can create the angled part easily with CSS, but I am having a tough time getting the box-shadow right. The issue is, I only need the box-shadow on the bottom of the before, after pseudo elements. But it is being added to all sides, so when the two elements meet in the middle to form the point the box-shadows overlap.

See here for example:

[image]

Here's what I have so far (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47zqjzmf/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.inner:before, .inner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: calc(50% + 5px);
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px #000;
}

.inner:before {
  left: -2px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.inner:after {
  right: -2px;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box-shadow` won't help you, because as the property name says, it's for boxes. The thing that will help you is `filter: drop-shadow()`. Also, instead of creating these two pseudoelement rectangles you can use `clip-path` property.

```css
.element {
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 15px black);
}

.element__clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%, 0 0);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="element__clip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ultrices, lorem id pellentesque sollicitudin, mauris massa aliquam velit, ut sagittis tellus justo non turpis. In tempor at dui et placerat. Aliquam dolor lorem, maximus non nunc sit amet, condimentum aliquam neque. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam laoreet purus sed arcu elementum varius. Nullam ante tortor, elementum sit amet justo vel, mollis dapibus massa. Sed ultricies dapibus eros ac laoreet. Maecenas posuere arcu enim, non interdum ipsum vulputate nec. Nulla iaculis orci ac mattis accumsan. Praesent id auctor ipsum. Aenean cursus arcu placerat nunc consectetur, feugiat tincidunt felis placerat. Quisque id sagittis mi. Curabitur tincidunt consequat orci, eu congue metus ultrices at. Aenean luctus justo et pharetra tristique.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. What would be the best cross-browser approach for using filter and clip-path? I'm guessing there would be no fallbacks for these for older browsers?

Comment: Here's the polyfill for `filter: drop-shadow()`: https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill
And here's for `clip-path`: https://github.com/AlfonsoFilho/ClipPath
I don't know if they will work together thought.

Comment: But `filter` has quite good browser support [according to CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). Only [`clip-path`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks) isn't supported in IE nor Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add different values to the X-axis of the shadows, for them not to overlap.

```
.inner:before {box-shadow: -2px 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}
.inner:after {box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.inner:before, .inner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: calc(50% + 5px);
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.inner:before {
      box-shadow: -2px 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.inner:after {
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.inner:before {
    left: -2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(7deg);
    transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.inner:after {
  right: -2px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-7deg);
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really close. However, when I increase the spread of the box-shadow I still get the overlap - see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/47zqjzmf/4/. Spread and rgba need to be quite high as per the design I am working to. Any ideas? *edit: updated jsfiddle link

Comment: I tested a bunch of different solutions with CSS triangles and transforms, but none of them worked as well as this. My suggestion is to play around with the box-shadow and values. As a designer, I usually don't like big spread values and dark shadows, more subtle shadows look more professional. You can also use a gradient from black to the bg-color on the next div. The shadow won't have the shape of a triangle, but will still look like it's underneath. Hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
.inner:before, .inner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: calc(50% + 5px);
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px -1px #000000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47zqjzmf/2/

Answer (score 0):

Tried a different solution, with gradient background. It's not like a triangular shadow, but still looks like the following div is underneath.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.inner:before, .inner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: calc(50% + 5px);
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.inner:before {
  left: -2px;
  transform: rotate(7deg);
}

.inner:after {
  right: -2px;
  transform: rotate(-7deg);
}


.content {
  padding: 20px;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#cccccc+0,ffffff+15,000000+100&0.65+0,0+100 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0.65) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,204,204,0.65) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,204,204,0.65) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.55) 15%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6cccccc', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```